# How can I update a rendered jade page with progress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I have a small express.js app with a form. On submit, it runs a python script that takes ~5 minutes to run and dumps messages to stdout while it runs. Right now I can call it and log the output to console just fine. I'd like for those messages to populate a span area (id=results) in my jade template until completion.

The route:

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  res.render('build', function(err, html) {
    res.send(html);
    var options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python',
      pythonOptions: ['-u'],
      scriptPath: '/test',
      args: ['test', '-t', req.body['type'], '-s', req.body['num'], req.body['name']]
    };
    var shell = new py('build', options);
    shell.on('message', function (message) {
      console.log(message);
    });
    shell.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
});
```

The jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  .container
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading: h3 Requesting a new Build
      .panel-body
        p
          | <span id='results'></span>

  script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js')
  script(src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

I've tried different variations of res.render and res.send but I think I'm barking up the wrong tree with those.

Comment: Jade templates render once. You'll have to set up some sort of polling, maybe with [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this with socket.io. Thanks for the quick tip @j4g. Added this to the end of my app.js:

```
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // this tells socket.io to use our express server

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A new user connected!');
});

app.set('socketio', io);
```

Then in my route:

```
  var socketio = req.app.get('socketio');
  shell.on('message', function (message) {
    socketio.emit('message', message);
  });
  shell.on('error', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
    socketio.emit('message', message);
  });
  shell.on('close', function() {
    socketio.emit('finish', 'Process completed.');
```

Then in my client JavaScript I added socket.io and this custom code:

```
var socket = io.connect(); 

socket.on('message', function (data) {
    $("#results").text(data);
});

socket.on('finish', function (data) {
    $("#results").text(data);
    $("#prog").text("Finished!");
    $(".progress-bar").removeClass('active').removeClass('progress-bar-striped');
});
```

I ended up replacing my span text instead of appending it, but either way it works as intended. Hopefully this can help someone else trying to do the same thing!

Comment: So, If I have many client? One message send to all clients, please.